# Comparing values to the empty set [] in Matlab in an if statement

Tags: matlab, if-statement, comparison

I would like to do stuff when a comparison evaluates to `[]` or `TRUE`.

For example, suppose the comparison is `x > 1` where x can be both of the following.

```
x = 2
x = []
```

I want to display 'yes' if `x > 1` gives `[]` or `TRUE`.

I could do

```
if x <= 1
    disp 'no'
else 
    disp 'yes'
end
```

But is there a straightforward way of doing this without negating the comparison operator?

EDIT in response to the first answer: I would like to avoid use of the `isempty` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [`all`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) function on the comparision

```
if all(x > 1)
    disp 'yes'
else
    disp 'no'
end
```

That's because

```
>> all([])
ans =
     1
>> all(1)
ans =
     1
```

You probably need to add a comment about why you use `all` on a scalar comparison for the future reader of that code (even if that is only you).

Answer (score 1):

```
if isempty(x) || x > 1
    disp 'yes'
else
    disp 'no'
end
```

Comment: thanks, this works but I do not want to have to explicitly type `isempty` as I will be working with many more variables in the if clause, and some of them, if empty, will result in the whole expression evaluating to empty.

Comment: @Alex then please make your example more representative of your problem as I do not understand what you mean in the comment above

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for both `isempty` and for our comparison, but in a comment you indicate that you're unwilling to type `isempty` directly for many variables. How about this? Then you'll only need to type `isempty` once.

```
mycomp = @(x) isempty(x) || x>1;

if mycomp(x)
    disp('yes')
else
    disp('no')
end
```